# Confused by behavior of `map` on arrays created using `new`

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, new-operator

I am confused by the results of `map`ping over an array created with `new`:

```
function returnsFourteen() {
    return 14;
}

var a = new Array(4);
> [undefined x 4] in Chrome, [, , , ,] in Firefox
a.map(returnsFourteen);
> [undefined x 4] in Chrome, [, , , ,] in Firefox

var b = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
> [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
b.map(returnsFourteen);
> [14, 14, 14, 14]
```

I expected `a.map(returnsFourteen)` to return `[14, 14, 14, 14]` (the same as `b.map(returnsFourteen)`, because according to the [MDN page on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 2**32-1 (inclusive), a new JavaScript array is created
>   with that number of elements.

I interpret that to mean that `a` should have 4 elements.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `.map()` works not in a *destructive* manner, try to assign the result back to `a`

Comment: The weird part is that if you do `console.log(a, b);` **before** any mapping it returns: `[undefined × 4] [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` (in Chrome)

Comment: @Neal: that is just `console` sugar. In reality, we have an `array` with a `length` of 4

Comment: @jAndy I understand that, the question is about the **return value**.

Comment: @jAndy ehhh they _should_ log the same thing, no?

Comment: @Neal: agreed, this behavior somehow gives the sense that some "instances" of "undefined" are less defined than others... =|

Comment: @Felix I would say this question is similar, but *not* identical because the crux of my problem is interpreting the MDN documentation.

Comment: @Matt: Then IMO this is not a good question for SO. You pointed out a controversial passage in the documentation, which is good, but can also be fixed and then the problem does not exist anymore. This is more suited as some kind of bug report or a discussion somewhere else IMO (for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array ).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create an array like so:

```
var arr1 = new Array( 4 );
```

you get an array that has a length of `4`, but that has *no* elements. That's why `map` doesn't tranform the array - the array has no elements to be transformed.

On the other hand, if you do:

```
var arr2 = [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ];
```

you get and array that also has a length of `4`, but that *does* have 4 elements.

Notice the difference between having no elements, and having elements which values are `undefined`. Unfortunately, the property accessor expression will evaluate to the `undefined` value in both cases, so:

```
arr1[0] // undefined
arr2[0] // undefined
```

However, there is a way to differentiate these two arrays:

```
'0' in arr1 // false
'0' in arr2 // true
```

Comment: additionally, most `console` objects behave really *confusing* on `Arrays` which just have a defined `.length`, but without real properties. I guess that should be part of the answer.

Comment: So is the quote from the MDN docs -- `a new JavaScript array is created with that number of elements` -- wrong, or have I misinterpreted it?  To me, it seems to mean that there actually are elements with values.

Comment: @MattFenwick: can you please link to the quote

Comment: @MattFenwick Yes, it is wrong. The newly created array does not have any elements. (Elements being own properties which names are indexes).

Comment: @jAndy Yea, my Firebug prints `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]` for both `arr1` and `arr2` (from my answer), which implies that both arrays have 4 elements. It'd be nice if they fixed that.

Answer (score 10):

```
var a = new Array(4);
```

This defines a new array object with an explicit length of 4, but no elements.

```
var b = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

This defines a new array object with an implicit length of 4, with 4 elements, each with the value `undefined`.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which
>   have never been assigned values.

For array `a`, there are no elements that have been assigned values, so it does nothing.

For array `b`, there are four elements that have been assigned values (yes, `undefined` is a value), so it maps all four elements to the number `14`.

Comment: So is the quote from the MDN docs -- `a new JavaScript array is created with that number of elements` -- wrong, or have I misinterpreted it?  To me, it seems to mean that there actually are elements with values.

Comment: @MattFenwick the docs are correct. there is an important difference between an element *being* `undefined` and an element *having the value* `undefined`.

Comment: @jbabey But `new Array(4)` creates an array with *no* elements, so the MDN docs are not correct... According to MDN, that array would have 4 elements.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it does create an array with 4 elements, but those 4 elements do not have any values assigned. map will not iterate over elements that have never been assigned values.

Comment: @jbabey I don't agree. An array element is, [by definition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4), a property which property name is an array index (a non-negative integer number, or a string representing such a number: `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc.). The [algotithm for `new Array(len)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2) does not specify that any elements are added to the newly created array.

Comment: In addition, when `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is invoked with such array, the result will contain the `'length'` string, but no array index. Therefore, the array does not contain any elements, but merely the `'length'` property. Take a look at @jAndy 's answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

`new Array(len)` creates an empty array, and does something different than filling it with `undefined` values: It sets its length to `len`. So, it translates to this code:

```
var newArr = [];
newArr.length = len;
```

Let's have some fun with `newArr` (assuming that `len = 4`):

```
newArr.length; //4
newArr[1] === undefined; //true
newArr.hasOwnProperty(1); //false
```

This is because while the is 4 items long, it does not contain any of these 4 items. Imagine an empty bullet-clip: It has space for, say, 20 bullets, but it doesn't contain any of them. They weren't even set to the value `undefined`, they just are...undefined (which is a bit confusing.)

Now, `Array.prototype.map` happily walks along your first array, chirping and whistling, and every time it sees an array item, it calls a function on it. But, as it walks along the empty bullet-clip, it sees no bullets. Sure, there are room for bullets, but that doesn't make them exist. In here, there is no value, because the key which maps to that value does not exist.

For the second array, which is filled with `undefined` values, the *value* is `undefined`, and so is the key. There is *something* inside `b[1]` or `b[3]`, but that something isn't defined; but `Array.prototype.map` doesn't care, it'll operate on any value, as long as it has a key.

For further inspection in the spec:

- `new Array(len)` : http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.2.2
- `Array.prototype.map` : http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.19 (pay close attention to step 8.b)

Comment: As I've asked the other answerers -- is the quote (`a new JavaScript array is created with that number of elements`) from the docs wrong or have I misinterpreted it?

Comment: @MattFenwick It's partially correct, which means it's mostly wrong and misleading. There is the capacity for that number of elements (there always is), but the elements themselves don't exist there.

Answer (score 1):

One additional answer on the behavior of `console.log`. Plain simple, the output is *sugar* and technically **wrong**.

Lets consider this example:

```
var foo = new Array(4),
    bar = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];

console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bar) );
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo) );
```

As we can see in the result, the `.getOwnPropertyNames` function returns

```
["length"]
```

for the `foo` Array/Object, but

```
["length", "0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

for the `bar` Array/Object.

So, the `console.log` just fools you on outputting `Arrays` which just have a defined `.length` but no real property assignments.

Comment: Actually, the console output wasn't a problem on my browsers.  The real issue was my misunderstanding/confusion of the MDN docs.